# Inserting in a multiset: before the first occurence of that value instead of after the last occurence

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

As the title says multiset inserts a value at the end of the range of all the same values.

(Ex: Inserting 2 in a multiset `1,2,2,3` makes it `1,2,2,/*new*/ 2,3`).

How do I get the new value inserted at the start of the range of all the same values?

(Ex: Inserting 2 in multiset `1,2,2,3` should make `1,/*new*/ 2,2,2,3`)

Comment: Can't you reverse the whole multiset? `std::multiset<int, greater<int>>` and use `reverse_iterator` for iteration?

Comment: Well given it has other uses I don't think it a good solution. @Jarod42

Comment: Better example would be with `std::pair<ValueType, IdType>` comparing only `ValueType` as for `int`, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Jarod42 https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b8bf82c66662e8d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
std::multiset<int> mset { 2,4,5,5,6,6 }; 
int val = 5;
auto it = mset.equal_range ( val ).first; //Find the first occurrence of your target value.  Function will return an iterator

mset.insert ( it, val );  //insert the value using the iterator
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `insert(iterator hint, const value_type& value)` instead of `insert(const value_type& value)`. As per documentation, this will insert before the `hint`. You can use `std::multiset::equal_range` to get the iterator to the lower bound.